# How to retrieve an object by an uuid' in Django

Tags: python, django

I would like to access my model by its pk field when it's an uuid representation. I'm getting an error of age not found 404`on this address`http://localhost:8002/box/6d99a390-5a8a-41e6-8fbf-84a2bb7a8e0f`
I have this configuration

```
def get_box(request, pk):
    """ 
    Retrieve the object 
    """
    box = get_object_or_404(Box, pk=pk)
    return render(
            request,
            'boxes/box.html',
            {'box':box}
            )
```

and for my models.py

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Box(models.Model):
    """
    Box model
    """
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True,
                              default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)     
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
```

and for my urls.py

```
...
url(r'^box/(?P<pk>[0-9A-Za-z]+)/$', views.get_box, name='box'),
...
```

Comment: Whats the error? no reverse match?

Comment: @Sayse no I have this error `The current URL, box/6d99a390-5a8a-41e6-8fbf-84a2bb7a8e0f, didn't match any of these.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not the query, but the URL. Your regex only matches against alphanumeric characters, but the uuid also contains dashes; you should include those in the pattern:

```
r'^box/(?P<pk>[0-9A-Fa-f-]+)/$'
```

(Note also that the characters can only be a to f, not a to z.)